# Associative array to String and String to associative array

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have to convert `an associative array to string` in `php`. I am doing this as

```
  $cookieValue = http_build_query(arr,'','SEP');
```

And I am setting a cookie by using `setcookie`.

```
  setcookie('subs',$cookieValue,0,'/');
```

Cookie in JS side looks like

```
 "emailID=a1%40a.comSEPmaths=0SEPphysics=1SEPchemistry=2SEPbotany=3SEPzoology=4SE
 Ptamil=5SEPenglish=6SEPpolity=7SEPgk=8SEPhistory=9"
```

I am trying to convert it back to associative array.

I just tried `JSON.parse`. It's not useful in my case.

I am free to change both `php side and js side functions`. But my aim is It should be easy to convert forth and back.

I tried `implode` on php also.

Comment: JSON.parse on that string ? :D sure it wont work ...

Comment: I thought it was JSON object `{'key'='value',...}`. But then I came to know it was not

Comment: use `$cookieValue = json_encode(arr)`

Comment: Create JSON on the PHP side (and object with multiple properties/values), then you can use `JSON.parse()` on it in Javascript.  Don't use query strings for this type of thing.

Comment: Thanks, Solved the issue

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```js
var a = "emailID=a1%40a.comSEPmaths=0SEPphysics=1SEPchemistry=2SEPbotany=3SEPzoology=4SEPtamil=5SEPenglish=6SEPpolity=7SEPgk=8SEPhistory=9";

 var myarr = {};
var sep = "SEP";
 a.split(sep).forEach(function(item){
     var sepp = item.indexOf("=");
     myarr[item.substr(0,sepp)] = decodeURIComponent(item.substr(sepp+1));
 });
console.log(myarr);
```

Here's a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/h5b0ek20/).

Answer (score 0):

you send data from js after converting to string using...

```
JSON.stringify(data);
```

and get form php side and convert using ..

```
$x = json_decode(array,true);
print_r($x);
```

you can get the array